# In PHP, is there a shorthand for $this-> when referencing other methods/properties within the same object?

Tags: php, php-7

I find myself using lots of property and method internal referencing with $this-> when writing new classes. I have searched far and wide and can't find anything but I was wondering if there is shorthand for this or a way to create shorthand.

When using external objects/classes, you can obviously do something like:

```
$t = new Class();
$t->method();
```

It seems like php would benefit from a nice terse this reference like $->my_method().

Comment: You could probably get your IDE to autocomplete `$->` to `$this->`, I suppose. I'm dubious of the value here, though.

Comment: It's not loads to write, but can be slightly annoying.  If it's an object property, I sometimes do something like $db = $this->dbh, but it doesn't really buy me that much.

Comment: Yes, I agree that setting up a custom autocomplete doesn't help much. I was just curious if PHP had a built in shorthand convention mostly, like they do for lots of other things.